# PHP login object constructor (extend class) logic

Tags: php

I have a login system that creates a USER object from class on login, I am interested to make it better by extending User class to Admin, Staff, Moderator and so on.

Each class will have its own functions / abilities that is the idea, however I am not sure how to do the following.

Currently I do this:
`$user = new User();`

Than this $user tries to log in and so on.

How can i do something like this:
`$user->login()` if user is admin create `$admin = new Admin()`;

I am having trouble with the logic part I believe..

Thank you

Additional my current user constructor:

```
public function __construct($user = null){
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
        $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');

        if(!$user){
            if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)){
                $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);
                if($this->find($user)){
                    $this->_isLoggedIn = TRUE;
                    // GRAB THE ID of user for pulling info from the personal
                    $userId = $this->_data->id;
                    $this->_data = $this->data();
                }else{
                    $this->logout();}
            }
        }else {
            $this->find($user);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why your User constructor knows to work with sessions? Where is the SOLID principle? Here just an very simplified example. The idea for creating different user types is to use Factory pattern. I assume that user's type stored in the user table in db.

Basically, you need:

```
class User
class Admin inherits User
class Moderator inherits User
class Auth // knows to do authorization
class UserFactory // knows to create needed user


class UserFactory
{
    public static function create($data)
    {
       $type = $userData['type'];

       switch ($type) {
        case "admin":
            return new Admin($data);
            break;
        case "moderator":
            return new Moderator ($data);
            break;
        default:
            return new User($data);
       }
    }
}

class Auth() {

   public login($username, $password) {
      // work with sessions, database
      $userData = $this->data();

      $user = UserFactory::create($userData);
      return $user;
  }
}

// just as an example
$auth = new Auth();
$user = $auth->login($username, $password);
```

Comment: Ok I get the idea of what you are doing here thanks I will give this a go. I understand the logic of this I think I will be able to work with it. And to add yes, usertype is stored in a DB table

Answer (score -1):

use `dependency injection`:

```
function createUser(User user){
    $this->user = user;
}
```

you can pass User, Admin ... to this function